# How to make separate lists out of multiple dataframe columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe

Yep, much discussed and similar questions down voted multiple times.. I still can't figure this one  out..

Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

I want to end up with four separate list (a, b, c and d) with the data from each column.

Logically (to me anyway) I would do:

```
list_of_lst = df.values.T.astype(str).tolist()

for column in df.columns:
    i = 0
    while i < len(df.columns) - 1:
        column = list_of_lst[1]
        i = i + 1
```

But assigning variable names in a loop is not doable/recommended...

Any suggestions how I can get what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best is create `dictionary of list` by [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
np.random.seed(456) 

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  5  9  4  5
1  7  1  8  3
2  5  2  4  2
3  2  8  4  8
4  5  6  0  9
5  8  2  3  6
6  7  0  0  3
7  3  5  6  6
8  3  8  9  6
9  5  1  6  1

d = df.to_dict('l')
print (d['A'])
[5, 7, 5, 2, 5, 8, 7, 3, 3, 5]
```

If really want `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` lists:

```
for k, v in df.to_dict('l').items():
     globals()[k] = v

print (A)
[5, 7, 5, 2, 5, 8, 7, 3, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Once again you come to my rescue:) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
retList = dict()
for i in df.columns:
    iterator = df[i].tolist()
    retList[i] = iterator
```

You'd get a dictionary with the keys as the column names and values as the list of values in that column.

Modify it to any data structure you want.

`retList.values()` will give you a list of size 4 with each inner list being the list of each column values

Comment: Hmm... So where are my four lists? I mean a,b,c and d?? I don't need them inside anything, I already had that.. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: retList.values()[0] - retList.values()[3] are your 4 lists

Comment: so to get what I need I have to do: a = retList.values()[0] b = etc etc?? That is not helping me at all, I got 25 columns in my original df..

Comment: okay I just made the connection that you wanted the column names to be the list_names.

you can check out @jezrael answer

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose your dataframe and use `df.T.values.tolist()`. But, if you are manipulating numeric arrays thereafter, it's advisable you skip the `tolist()` part.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

#     A   B   C   D
# 0  17  56  57  31
# 1   3  44  15   0
# 2  94  36  87  30
# 3  44  49  56  76
# 4  29   5  35  24

list_of_lists = df.T.values.tolist()

# [[17, 3, 94, 44, 29],
#  [56, 44, 36, 49, 5],
#  [57, 15, 87, 56, 35],
#  [31, 0, 30, 76, 24]]
```